# How does Windows 7 store a mapped network drive? I have one that cannot be deleted, and connects in spite of a required VPN being inactive

Tags: windows-7, vpn, routing, shared-folders

When I type `\\192.168.1.2\` into Windows Explorer on my desktop, it is connecting to another one of my servers halfway across the state of Pennsylvania and I have no idea how.

I have absolutely no idea how it is translating the address 192.168.1.2 to the remote server.

I have run the "route print" command in the windows command prompt, and there is nothing there pointing to the remote server.

Does anyone know how this might be possible or where Windows may be storing the information it needs to make this connection?

This could be some kind of bug.  Originally, I had a VPN connection set up so that the address 192.168.1.* range would map to the remote server, it's address being 192.168.1.2.  I used Routing and Remote Access services on the remote server, and the built-in VPN connection for Windows 7 on the local machine.  The problem now is that this mapped drive persists in windows explorer, and I cannot delete it.  The VPN connection is closed/inactive, and yet the local machine is still connecting to the remote shared drive.

Could it be a problem with my D-LINK switch caching something?

UPDATE: I ran the command `netstat -an` to list all active connection, and noticed that the only unrecognized connection is on port 445, but it's listed as an IPV6 address.  I'm guessing that's the remote server in question, but how and why has Windows saved that address?

Comment: There's no mention of a mapped drive anywhere in your question's body?  Have you tried a `ipconfig /flushdns` yet?  If you run `nslookup 192.168.1.2` does it resolve to the name of the server?

Comment: I did mention a mapped drive: "The problem now is that this mapped drive persists in windows explorer...".  Anyway, nslookup resolves nothing, and I ran flushdns with no results.

There's a number of problems here.  First, the mapped drive is showing up in Explorer, with a red X, and I cannot disconnect or delete it.  Deleting the corresponding registry key (HKCU/Network) while explorer.exe is terminated, and restarting it does not make it go away.  Secondly, if I then connect a VPN to a completely different server (Server B), the drive suddenly becomes available, but connects to Server A.

Comment: The mapped drive is persisting, cannot be deleted, and connects to a server it should not be connecting to.  That's server's VPN is inactive, and if I connect to a completely different VPN, the mapped drive establishes a connection to the original server, which has no associating with the active VPN.

Comment: If I kill the explorer process, delete the mapped drive registry key under HKCU/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Explorer/MountPoints, ##192.168.1.2#wwwroot, the key just comes back once I start Explorer again and open my computer.  It has to be storing this information in at least 3 locations, because I also deleted the one under HKCU/Network.

Comment: The mystery is solved.  What a perfect storm of allowable, but ultimately conflicting results.  See my posted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  Here's an illustration, followed by a text explanation of what was going on.

[image]

First of all, any mapped drive needs to be connected in order to delete it.  That seems to be a general issue with mapped drives in Windows.

Second, the reason the Client was able to connect to Server B, despite the only active VPN from the Client being to Server A, is that Server B also had established a VPN connection to Server A, using the same Windows account as the Client.

The issue was a freak VPN address conflict of sorts, that arose from not only using the same account for two different clients ("The Client" and "Server B"), but the order in which they connected, and the fallback address windows chose conflicted with the server's own loopback adapter address.

Normally, the Client and Server B each have their own user account for dialing in to the VPN of Server A, and they each had different static IP's assign in their user accounts Dial-In tab, so normally the Client and Server B would each get their own static IP without any conflict.

For some reason, instead of using Server B's own account, I had used the client's account to connect, which is basically my main user account... a simple mistake.  I noticed this in RRAS, when I saw two clients were connected under the same username.  I know one was my client machine, but the other had been active for over 900 hours.  That's when I realized it must be Server B connecting to Server A, but it failed to use its own user account.
So that's where it got interesting.  Some time 900+ hours ago, the client must have connected first, and received the proper static IP: 192.168.1.101.  Then Server B must have connected afterwards while the client's VPN was still active, and since the client was already logged in under that same account, it could not be assigned the chosen static IP, so Windows just decided to fall back to the next IP address available in the static routes range, which happened to be 192.168.1.2.  So Server B now has an VPN IP address of 192.168.1.2.  Which would be fine except...

That's a problem, because that's the IP (192.168.1.2) I assigned to Server A's loopback adapter.  That's supposed to be the IP I use to access Server A on the VPN when the client is connected, except now Server B thinks it's also 192.168.1.2.

So there was an undetectable IP address conflict going on, which explains the bizarre behavior.  Namely, that when I first connected to the VPN for Server A, the address 192.168.1.2 was routing to Server B, and if I simply disconnected and reconnected the drive to that same IP, it would find Server A instead.  I'm not sure how windows makes the decision of which computer to route to when an RRAS client and the Microsoft Loopback adapter end up assign to the same IP address.

Honestly, this is a dumb bug in Windows Server, because the RRAS server should have known to not assign an IP address in the given range that was already taken by another adapter (the loopback adapter).  Perhaps it only tracks IPs and tests for conflicts with IPs it assigns itself, and doesn't have any way of knowing whether existing adapters are already using an IP in the allowed range.

The whole thing was a freak combination of events... Server B connected after Server A using the same account instead of its own, since the static IP for that account was already taken, RRAS then stupidly assigned an IP address to it from the allowed range, without first checking for conflicts, and it ended up giving Server B the same IP as Server A's loopback adapter.  Then when the client tried to access that IP, Windows would thing it was Server B at first, but a disconnect/reconnect of the mapped drive to that same IP would then resolve to Server A.  Incredibly strange.

In any case, all I have to do is bump the allowed range from 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.3, so it never assigns it's own static IP to any clients, which wasn't supposed to happen, given that they all were assigned their own static IPs, except that when they connected with the same account, it had no choice but to fall back to something in the allowed range.